# Remove extra line breaks from Jest Test Snapshot?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

In my vanilla html Jest snapshot, there are **three line breaks** after most elements. For larger snapshots, it would be more readable if the serialization was compact with no extra line breaks.

I've tried adding a **custom serializer** as recommended by [pretty formatter](https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/packages/pretty-format#config) adding `min: true` to the config but it doesn't not remove the extra new line characters. I have also tried returning a string from the `serialize` method removing all new line break characters.

```
// custom-snapshot-serializer.js
const prettyFormat = require('pretty-format');

module.exports = {
    test: (val) => typeof val === 'string',

    serialize: (val) => prettyFormat(val),

    config: {min: true, spacingInner: '', spacingOuter: ''}
};
```

Here is what the snapshot currently looks like with extra line breaks:

[image: snapshot]

Comment: Vue has serializer that solves this issue, might be worth looking into source code to adopt for vanilla html too https://github.com/tjw-lint/jest-serializer-vue-tjw